# JQuery UI Resize Handle not correct

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've created this fiddle that shows an issue i'm having http://jsfiddle.net/8FBW5/1/

You can see that the little handle to re-size isn't wrapped around the contents of the div.  I could manually set the size, but that will be cumbersome as i'll be adding/removing elements.

Doing something like

```
#field{
    height: 34px;
}
```

isn't what i want to do to get the handle in the correct position.  Is there a setting that will make it so that the handle appears at the appropriate place?

Comment: What about doing an `overflow: hidden` http://jsfiddle.net/8FBW5/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8FBW5/4/ For me, that seems to move the resize handle away from my cursor on first resize.  It looks like its smashing everything together, then doing a normal resize.  Do you have that issue?

Comment: Also, why does overflow hidden do that?  My (incorrect) understanding of what should happen there is that everything would be hidden because the div has no height.

Comment: I added the following CSS to your DIV and it seems to fix the issues: `border:1px solid black; overflow:hidden; padding-bottom:20px; width:100%;`. (The "border" CSS is just to see the DIV better.)

Comment: You can change the Icon of handle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The catch is that all of the elements inside the `#field` div are floated. This makes it have height of `0`. See [All About Floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) article, mainly chapter "The Great Collapse" for an explanation why is this seemingly wrong behavior actually necessary. The site is a good source for CSS stuff altogether.

One way to solve this is a so-called "clearfix". And one way of achieving that is with an `:after` pseudo-element:

```
#field:after {
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    content: "";
}
```

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UyDC4/2/

For a quick reference (and the evolution of browser support), see http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

---

Another way to make the container stretch to the expected height is to add a new element just before closing it: `<div style"clear: both;"></div>`. This is in principle the same technique as with the pseudo element, but is better supported in ancient browsers (sorry IE<8 but nowadays you're ancient). On the downside, there is this non-semantic new HTML element that many people would consider ugly.

Yet another way is to set `overflow: hidden;` on the parent element. I find this method is the most poorly documented on the Net, and that's probably for a good reason. While it will work just fine for making the container element stretch vertically, it will also (obviously enough) change its `overflow` behavior. In many situations this might be undesirable. Here is a discussion of that technique: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html